# How to get a response header when load an image in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

The same url will return different image(random), and I need to get the response's header(also will be different in each times), so I can not fetch twice.

I try to use the `blob`, but get a warn that said `'blob' is undefined`, the code like this:

```
let response = await fetch(URLs.host + URLs.imageCode);
let key = response.headers.get('key');
console.log(response.blob); // this will print 'undefined'
let blob = await response.blob();
this.setState({source: URL.createObjectURL(blob)});

...

<Image source={{uri: this.state.source}} />
```

So how can I get the header when load the image?

Comment: which fetch library are you using? Also what is key in the headers object? Check if response.headers.status exists and is 200. Then you should be able to get your data in response.body. Also if await is a generator you might need to use yield to get the body after the headers are returned from fetch.

Comment: @user874639: "*if await is a generator*" doesn't make sense, but otherwise +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use fetch to get a blob in React-Native per [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/854) because fetch is a native http call that stores the blob on the native level and doesn't provide a reference to the actual memory to the javaScript blob object in `res.blob()`

Best option until someone writes a bridge for this is to use base64 encoded images which is just a string so you can get it with `res.text()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found now we can not get the context when load an image by use `{{uri: xxx}}` in react-native, so my solution is talk to the server develper and let they design the API in an other way.